# C++ condition_variable mutex lock issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to use std::condition_variable for my multithreading purposes but it requires a lock which is big negative for me. Before I just created new threads on the spot but creating new threads and takes too much time. So I looked to conditional variable but it locks that function so only thread can execute it at a time. I would have create many copies of ExecutionWorker() and rename them like ExecutionWorker1(), ExecutionWorker2(),ExecutionWorker3(),ExecutionWorker4() ... and so on. Then create new thread for each function and use condition variable which would make it effectively lock free if I use different mutex for each function copy but I dont want to do that too messy.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do? I need multiple threads to exeute from execVec queue at once. At the present moment with condition variable and mutex loc, some of those functions in execVec will have Sleep() and so only after all that is done then mutex is unlocked and locked again when another thread takes the job so effectively is only one thread executing at a time

```
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable condition;
std::vector<void(__cdecl*)()> execVec;

void ExecutionWorker()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        p_IScript->condition.wait(locker, []() -> bool { return execVec.size() > 0; });

        // execute  a member of execVec here
        // imagine it takes 5 seconds so Sleep(5000) will replace that code

        execItem();

        Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to lock when pushing to and popping from the vector. Execute the function outside the lock scope. For example:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

class task_queue
{
public:
    using task = std::function<void ()>;

private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::queue<task> tasks;

public:
    void push_task(task t)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            tasks.push(t);
        }

        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void process_tasks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            task t;

            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
                cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return !tasks.empty(); });
                t = tasks.back();
                tasks.pop();
            }

            t();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: but I need to use std::condition_variable, which requires a lock

Comment: @Budskii You only need to lock when popping from the vector. Execute the function outside the lock scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of an `execVec` element under a lock, and execute it later without a lock, along the lines of the following:

```
while(true)
{
    decltype(execVec)::value_type execItem;

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        p_IScript->condition.wait(locker, []() -> bool { return execVec.size() > 0; });
        execItem = execVec.back();
        execVec.pop_back();
    }

    // This code is executed outside the lock scope,
    // so it doesn't affect the execution of other threads.
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: I need a few threads to wait for a signal from std::condition_variable thats what the condition.wait(locker...) is for in the code incase you didn't notice and then once it receives a signal execute some function in the execVec vector. I have no problem poping the vector, it's just that std::condition_variable requires a lock and after it receives a signal it stays locked until it's done executing and when it returns back to condition.wait(locker...)

Comment: @Budskii The mutex only remains locked over the lifetime of the lock. The function is called outside the scope of `locker`, so multiple functions can run simultaneously no problem.

Comment: @Budskii you need a lock anyway for thread safety of operations with the vector. And the actual processing is done outside the lock scope.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for help.

It was quite simple, as you all suggested all I had to was to use unique_lock in another scope so when it executed it unlocked again.

Here is the final solution self-sufficient compilable code which tbh I should have posted in the starting post..

```
std::condition_variable cond;
std::mutex mu;
std::queue<void(__cdecl*)()> execQueue;

typedef void (__cdecl* callback)();

callback RequestAcces(scrQueueReqType type, callback func = nullptr)
{
    MUTEX_LOCK_GUARD;
    if(type == QUEUE_ADDJOB)
    {
        execQueue.push(func);
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        callback retfunc = execQueue.front();
        execQueue.pop();
        return retfunc;
    }
}

void Worker()
{
    while(true)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            cond.wait(locker, []() -> bool {return !execQueue.empty();} );
        }

        callback to_exec = RequestAcces(QUEUE_GETJOB);
        to_exec();
    }
}

void main()
{
    std::thread t1(Worker);
    std::thread t2(Worker);
    std::thread t3(Worker);

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    t3.detach();

    while(true)
    {
        auto func = []()
        {
            printf("This job was completed by threadId: 0x%X\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
            Sleep(3000);
        };

        RequestAcces(QUEUE_ADDJOB, func);
        cond.notify_one();
        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `MUTEX_LOCK_GUARD` is a `std::lock_guard` of `mu`, you are unnecessarily locking the mutex twice per vector access. Anton's solution (what I was suggesting) is more efficient.

Comment: In fact, there is no guarantee that the queue hasn't been emptied before `RequestAcces` is called. So your code is not safe.

Comment: Ok so your and his suggestion is to make a copy of the value under lock, but what if elsewhere in the code it pushes a job inthe queue after you've copied last element but haven't pop'd last element yet? so you get element = queue.back(); (here another thread pushes onto queue) and now back in other thread you pop_back() .. it will pop wrong one. I had a problem like this before, and had to put reading/writing under one function for vectors used in multithreading.

Comment: Also you're right about no guarantee that the queue hasn't been emptied before RequestAcces is called. I did come across that problem after I posted the code and had to change it a little to this: `scrQueueRet_s* scrQu = new scrQueueRet_s;
{
 std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
 p_IScript->condition.wait(locker, [&]() -> bool
 {
  RequestAccess(QUEUE_GETJOB, scrQu);
  return !scrQu->empty;
 });
}`

Comment: Any code that modifies the queue needs to lock the mutex first. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you seem to be over-complicating things. I have added an example of how to implement a task queue to my response.